# Why is Model.save() not working in Sails.js?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, sails.js, sails-mongo

Save() giving me error like "Object has no method 'save'"

```
Country.update({id:req.param('country_id')},model).exec(function(err,cntry){

         if(err) return res.json(err);

         if(!cntry.image){

               cntry.image = 'images/countries/'+filename;
               cntry.save(function(err){ console.log(err)});
         }
})
```

Any Idea about how to save model within update query . ??

Comment: Are you using Waterline and sails-mongo, or Mongoose?  Looks like Waterline to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using Waterline and sails-mongo, the issue here is that `update` returns an array (because you can update multiple records at once), and you're treating it like a single record.  Try:

```
Country.update({id:req.param('country_id')},model).exec(function(err,cntry){

         if(err) return res.json(err);

         if(cntry.length === 0) {return res.notFound();}

         if(!cntry[0].image){

               cntry[0].image = 'images/countries/'+filename;
               cntry[0].save(function(err){ console.log(err)});
         }
});
```

This seems to me an odd bit of code, though; why not just check for the presence of `image` in `model` before doing `Country.update` and alter `model` (or a copy thereof) accordingly?  That would save you an extra database call.

Answer (score 1):

When using mongoose (3.8) to update the database directly the callback function receives 3 parameters, none of then is a mongoose object of the defined model. The parameters are:

- err is the error if any occurred
- numberAffected is the count of updated documents Mongo reported
- rawResponse is the full response from Mongo

The right way is, first you fetch and then change the data:

```
Country.findOne({id: req.param('country_id')}, function (err, country) {
  // do changes
})
```

Or using the update method, the way you intended:

```
Country.update({id: req.param('country_id'), image: {$exists: false}}, {image: newValue}, callback)
```